# passing arguments in Externalinterface.call

Tags: actionscript-2, externalinterface

How would I pass these two arguments into Actionscript 2's externalinterface.call?

```
name: 'go'
params: {}
```

Why does this not work?

```
ExternalInterface.call("eventaction",({name: ‘go’,params: {}}));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the object literal syntax for each argument:

```
ExternalInterface.call("eventaction", {"name": "go"}, {"params": {} });
```

Comment: Is there any way to pass ... args from e.g. callFrontend(func:String, ... args:*) to the ExternalInterface.call arguments? So that I don't have to do this:

ExternalInterface.call(func, args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3]);